# SetDIBitsToDevice, StretchDIBits, VB6

Tags: gdi

I used to be good with these things but that was a long time ago!

I have a sample program for a frame grabber working fine, it uses this line (after some other stuff) to display the image in the PictureBox:

SetDIBitsToDevice(Picture1.hdc, 0, 0, gSizeX, gSizeY, 0, 0, 0, gSizeY, gSurfAddr, bmpInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS)

All I want to do is to change this so I can create a scaled image. So I changed this line to:

StretchDIBits(Picture1.hdc, 0, 0, w, h, 0, 0, gSizeX, gSizeY, gSurfAddr, bmpInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS, vbSrcCopy)
.. where w and h are the dimension of the image I want (I tried same as gSizeX/y at first, about 700 * 500).

But I get no image, sometimes just white, sometimes what looks like uninitialised memory.

Have I made a simple mistake or do I need to do more?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to call SetStretchBltMode before StretchDIBits. Sometimes resizing works incorrectly without SetStretchBltMode. Parameters: COLORONCOLOR (fast resizing), HALFTONE (high-quality resizing).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145089(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but it is the same. It now looks like this:

SetStretchBltMode Picture1.hdc, HALFTONE
StretchDIBits Picture1.hdc, 0, 0, gSizeX, gSizeY, 0, 0, gSizeX, gSizeY, gSurfAddr, bmpInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS, vbSrcCopy


(HALFTONE is 4)

Comment: Why can't I comment with carriage returns? Makes it very difficult showing code!

Comment: Thanks Alex that helped me solved image distortions when stretching down the image